# Freemarker directive or method with boolean return

Tags: java, customization, freemarker

I am trying to create a custom directive or method in Freemarker that performs a boolean check, e.g.

```
<#if foo = 'bar'>
do something
</#if>
```

should be equaivilant to

```
<@mycheck 'bar'>
do somethng
</@mycheck>
```

I already worked with custom directives and methods in Freemarker but I didn't find any way to create this with a boolean return.

**UPDATE**

To make it more clear what I want to do, consider the following: I want to check in a template if it is displayed at a certain URL.

So instead of passing a variable into the template and check via if, like

```
<#if location = '/home/bar'>
do something
</#if>
```

I want to do this a little more fluent like this

```
<@location is='/home/bar'>
do somethng
</@location>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any return value there (unless we consider the output itself as that). You can write a macro like this:

```
<#macro mycheck value>
  <#if foo == value>
    <#nested>
  </#if>
</#macro>
```

and then this should work (assuming you have a `foo` in the data-model or elsewhere where the macro can see it):

```
<@mycheck 'bar'>
do somethng
</@mycheck>
```

The solution with `TemplateDirectiveModel` is very similar, except that unfortunately the argument must be passed by name (`<@mycheck expected='bar'>...` or something similar), as of 2.3.25 at least. Instead of `<#nested>` you simply call `TemplateDirectiveBody.render(...)` in Java, and `#if` is just a Java `if` of course.

`TemplateMethodModel` can't be used for such purpose, as it can't do flow control.

Comment: Actually I need to do this via a directie or method, becaus I need to programmic checks on the input parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I will check out the Model again then. But it is actually not clear to me, how the model does the boolean check, because the model does not return boolean at all. WIth the model it looks to me I can handle the do something in the execute method rather than in the template.

Comment: There's not boolean (or any other) return value needed anywhere, assuming your original question was accurate. You just either call `TemplateDirectiveBody.render(...)` or not, and that's decided by your Java code inside `execute`. If you don't call it, the nested content will be skipped, just like with `<#if false>...</#if>`.